# Generalize code matching on constructors of types

Tags: coq

I'm working in the HoTT universe, so `discriminate` isn't available (yet!)

For each pair of constructors, I can construct a theorem using transport and type families, but I don't know how to generalize this pattern.  I would like to
create a tactic which would work in a similar way to `discriminate`, if that's
easier, rather than trying to phrase it as a theorem.

```
Lemma bool_discriminate (p : true = false) : Empty.
Proof.
    Fixpoint BoolFamily (b : Bool) : Type :=
        match b with
        |true => Unit
        |false => Empty
        end.
    exact (transport BoolFamily p tt).
Defined.

Lemma nat_discriminate (n : nat) (p : O = (S n)) : Empty.
Proof.
    Fixpoint NatFamily (x : nat) : Type :=
        match x with
        |O => Unit
        |(S _) => Empty
        end.
    exact (transport NatFamily p tt).
Defined.

Inductive threes : Type :=
    one | two | three.

Lemma threes_discriminate12 (p : one = two) : Empty.
Proof.
    Fixpoint ThreesFamily (x : threes) : Type :=
        match x with
        | one => Unit
        | two => Empty
        | three => Unit (* Could be anything *)
        end.
    exact (transport ThreesFamily p tt).
Defined.
```

Comment: I did something like this (for plain Coq, no HoTT) a while back, but I had to patch into the ocaml code of Coq to get the information about constructors and such. I know that since that time, writing plugin has become much easier, so maybe that the way to go. I don't think that Ltac has the power you need to build such terms, but adding an ml based tactic should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

This generalizes to the encode-decode pattern of HoTT.  Although you have to define the type of codes yourself (FooFamily, in your code), its size is linear in the number of constructors, and you don't have to do it separately for each pair of constructors.  For all enumeration types, you can write a tactic to prove the encode-decode proofs you need.

```
Inductive Empty := .
Inductive Unit := tt.
Inductive Bool := true | false.
Ltac prove_encode :=
  hnf in *;
  repeat match goal with
         | _ => progress subst
         | [ |- Unit ] => constructor
         | [ |- ?x = ?x ] => reflexivity
         | [ H : Empty |- _ ] => case H
         | [ H : Unit |- _ ] => destruct H
         | [ |- context[match ?x with _ => _ end] ]
           => is_var x; destruct x
         | [ H : context[match ?x with _ => _ end] |- _ ]
           => is_var x; destruct x
         | [ |- _ = _ ] => reflexivity
         | [ |- ?f _ _ (?g _ _ ?p) = ?p ] => unfold f, g
         end.
Definition Bool_code (x y : Bool)
  := match x, y with
     | true, true => Unit
     | true, _ => Empty
     | false, false => Unit
     | false, _ => Empty
     end.
Definition Bool_encode {x y} (p : x = y) : Bool_code x y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition Bool_decode {x y} (p : Bool_code x y) : x = y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition Bool_endecode {x y p} : @Bool_encode x y (Bool_decode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition Bool_deencode {x y p} : @Bool_decode x y (Bool_encode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.

Lemma bool_discriminate (p : true = false) : Empty.
Proof. exact (Bool_encode p). Qed.

Definition nat_code (x y : nat)
  := match x, y with
     | O, O => Unit
     | O, _ => Empty
     | S x', S y' => x' = y'
     | S _, _ => Empty
     end.
Definition nat_encode {x y} (p : x = y) : nat_code x y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition nat_decode {x y} (p : nat_code x y) : x = y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition nat_endecode {x y p} : @nat_encode x y (nat_decode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition nat_deencode {x y p} : @nat_decode x y (nat_encode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.

Lemma nat_discriminate (n : nat) (p : O = (S n)) : Empty.
Proof. exact (nat_encode p). Qed.

Inductive threes : Type :=
  one | two | three.

Definition threes_code (x y : threes)
  := match x, y with
     | one, one => Unit
     | one, _ => Empty
     | two, two => Unit
     | two, _ => Empty
     | three, three => Unit
     | three, _ => Empty
     end.
Definition threes_encode {x y} (p : x = y) : threes_code x y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition threes_decode {x y} (p : threes_code x y) : x = y.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition threes_endecode {x y p} : @threes_encode x y (threes_decode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.
Definition threes_deencode {x y p} : @threes_decode x y (threes_encode p) = p.
Proof. prove_encode. Defined.

Lemma threes_discriminate12 (p : one = two) : Empty.
Proof. exact (threes_encode p). Qed.
```